# How to get the Triggers total runtime that is left to my Account?

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

I have a script which is running daily, sometimes multiple.

I get an error because of the limitation of the Triggers total runtime. 
Is there a function / way, that I implement to proof, how much total trigger runtime is left to my account?

Every account has a daily limit of 6 hours per day and I want to implement something that tells me like: "Okay, you have 2 hours of total trigger runtime left for today".

Is there anything existing like that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this feature is not supported yet. You will have to write your own implementation of this, seeing that it's doable.

The way I would approach this is to insert your self-made trigger-counter code in your program. Save the number of trigger in a database somewhere, Firebase for example. Then write your code that fetches the trigger count everytime your program is triggered. I haven't implemented this yet but it's what I would do.